# Starting turn-by-turn with parameters in google maps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

i'm using the following code to open google maps

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=%@,%@",Latitude,Longitude];
[app openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

is there anyway to send some parameter to start the turn-by-turn imediatly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.co.in/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%@",userLocation.latitude,userLocation.longitude,address];
[app openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

here `address` can be any logical address.. like.. `Mumbai,India`